# Vertically Center a Div

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't this work (i.e. div content is not centred - vertically)?:

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="vertical-align: middle; display:table-cell; height: 100px; font-size: 11px;">
        <a target="_self" runat="server" href="~/daily.aspx">
        <img src="images.png" /></a>
            content in div<br />
     </div>
</div>
```

Googling everywhere in understanding how I can vertically align a div and it's content has failed.

Anybody any ideas in the best css styling for content in a div.

UPDATE
Need to explain that I need the text vertically aligned to the image not just the div. The text is bottom to the image. Might have to use floats.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error: http://jsfiddle.net/QtzRA/

Comment: That's what I was reading when I googling. It should have worked, but it isn't. Is it css version? Is it something to do with outer divs? I need to investigate further.

Comment: @Rob which browser are you using? works for me too.

Comment: IE9 and Firefox Beta 8. I'm looking at the website for doctypes, hidden a/img tag css overrides...

Comment: Sorry found out I did not explain myself clearly :(. I want the text to be vertically centred to the image. If the image is 60px and want the text to centred middle of image (30px) not div. I used div because I thought this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the text aligned in the middle of the text, this will do:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a target="_self" runat="server" href="~/daily.aspx">
        <img src="images.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"/></a>
        content in div<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/Tetaxa/tVQc6/

Comment: Thank you!!! Sorry to everyone else for my initial question not being explained properly. Can't believe how simple this is. Thanks again.

Comment: well, the `img` is positioned inline, so the line-height will be adjusted for that line. if you want the text to break to several lines on the side of the image, you need to position the `img` absolutely or float it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying an element as a table, why not use a table?

As far as I know though, it is not possible to center content unless you know it's height. IF you know the height you can use something like this:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.vertical {
    position: absolute:
    top: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px; // This is half the height
}
```

Comment: Good point about using a table :) But I hate using tables for something so small. I did have the height defined in my example, but I will try your example and see if it works. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Rob Do not use `<table>` elements for non-tabulair data, **especially not for styling purposes**.

Comment: I wasn't aware it wasn't tabular data, but this code definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

why dont You try using `<table>`? or do u want to do it with `<div>` itself?

Comment: Because it's not tabular data, he shouldn't be using a table

Comment: I agree with everyone who suggested not using a table for this example :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question,

but did anyone try display:table/table-cell/table-row instead? That should be fine. 
(ofcourse not working on older IE etc.)

Types from W3Schoools:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

These types can be set to any html element, and it should render as a part of a table (or a table itself).
This meaning you should be able to use divs to render data as if it was in a table.
I have not tested this though and the last time I used this was years ago.

able    The element is displayed as a table 
table-caption   The element is displayed as a table caption 
table-cell  The element is displayed as a table cell
table-column    The element is displayed as a table column
table-column-group  The element is displayed as a table column group (like )
table-footer-group  The element is displayed as a table footer row group
table-header-group  The element is displayed as a table header row group
table-row   The element is displayed as a table row 
table-row-group The element is displayed as a table row group

Comment: Could you expand on this a little bit? Try how?

Comment: I did, but I don't think you'll use it ;)