# Vertically center a Div inside a Div

Tags: html, css

I wrote the below program to get notifications from the database and display it. The situation was to display the `div` inside `div.note` *vertically centered*.

I tried `vertical-align: middle` and `vertical-align: center` and both failed. I found that they are for table cell. So I opted this.

```
<?php
include("../common/config.php");
$query = "SELECT content FROM st_notifications";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<div class='note'><div style='word-wrap: break-word;'>".$row[0]."</div></div>";
}
?>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".note").each(function () {
            var note = $(this);
            var diff = 100 - ($("div", note).outerHeight() / 2);
            $("div", note).css({ 'margin-top': diff >= 0 ? diff : 0 });
        });
    });
</script>
```

the output was something like this.

[image]

The css of `.note` is:

```
.note {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 25px auto 0px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-image: url(../images/notebg.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

The output on Chrome debugger was:

[image]

You can see that both the margins are `100px` instead of being assigned relatively.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913613/vertically-center-a-div). But don't know how to relate it to my problem

And the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279831/how-to-center-vertically-child-elements-inside-div) seems to be incredibly long.

Can somebody tell where I am wrong? Thanks in advance.

PS: 
I tried jQuery by directly calling the element and using each() function both give the same. And there is no debugging error in Chrome regarding JavaScripts or PHP.

Comment: [Chapter 9 - Positioning: Advanced - Pro CSS and HTML Design Patterns - Written by Michael Bowers. Published by apress® on April 23, 2007.](http://cssdesignpatterns.com/Chapter%2009%20-%20POSITIONING3/index.html) - just pick what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: table-cell;` to align the nested div vertically centered

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8QjZN/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper"><div class="inner">This is vertically centered</div></div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    text-align: center;
}

div.inner {
    display: inline-block; /* This is optional */
}
```

If the `div` is fixed

Way 2 [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nJuQ/)

HTML

```
<div class="container"><div class="float">This will work with fixed dimensions</div></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
}

.float {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px; /* Half Of Width */
    margin-top: -25px; /* Half Of Height */
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

Comment: I agree with @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin. I am designing a web page for my college and I dont want any different views, please. I also mentioned I have already tried those methods.

Comment: @GopikrishnaS I can give you another solution if the width is fixed

Answer (score 2):

Set the inner div's position to absolute and top as 50%.
Play with the position and top,left attributes to get your positioning correct.
Try having your parent div's position as relative if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, no success in setting the position to absolute.

Answer (score 0):

**JQUERY Solution**

I am using this function I created some day:

```
/**
 * Permits to center an element vertically in its parent
 * The div to center must exist before calling this function
 * @param : element => div to center
 * @param : offset => offset to apply
 * @param : parent => center into a parent, by default, window size is used
 */
function centerDivVertically(element,offset,parent)
{
    parent = parent || null;

    var myOffset = (offset != null) ? offset : 0;
    var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();

    //Align to the parent
    if(parent != null)
        height = $(parent).height();

    var elementHeight = height - $(element).height();
    $(element).css('top',(elementHeight/2)+myOffset + 'px');    
}

//Usage
centerDivVertically('#myDiv',0,null);
```

Comment: Thank you friend, but why you need to calculate the `window.height`?

Comment: The window height calculation is done using different methods depending on the browser : ´var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();´

Comment: this gives the same result `top: 100px` like mine where it gives `margin-top: 100px` @sdespont

Answer (score 0):

```
.outer {
    width: Xpx;
    height: Ypx;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.inner {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/tUX5Z/
​